# Functional Extremum Problem with inhomgeneous boundary condition

Tags: functional-analysis, optimal-control

How to solve a functional extremum problem where the boundary condition is inhomogeneous? let's say
$$\begin{aligned}&\max_{F}\int_p^11-F(v)dv\\
s.t.& 1-F(p)-pF'(p)=0\\ &F(p) \text{ is a cumulative distribution function(CDF) over } [0,1]\end{aligned},$$
where $p\in(0,1)$. If the inhomogeneous boundary condition does not exist, I know how to solve this problem. Now with it, it seems very hard to evaluate.

Comment: The equation seems to be $(pF(p))'=0$ ? maybe this can helpe

Comment: @daw It does not work. Since if I replace the functional with $vF(v)$, another restriction, $F'(p)\geq 0$, becomes inhomogeneous, then the same problem appears.